# move jquery slider with text links

Tags: jquery, slider

i have to modify this page https://www.bcidaho.com/healthcare-reform/timeline.asp to use text links to move the slider to the relevant content.

the text links will be the months/years at the bottom of the slider.

right now i just uses the default handle on the slider.

just looking for insight on where to begin my quest for a solution.

thx

Comment: Please include the relevant code snippets in you question.

Comment: Side Note: Have you thought about updating to jQuery 1.4.2 & jQuery UI 1.8.5?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `value` method to get (not specifying `[value]`) or set (specify `[value]`) the value.

```
.slider( "value" , [value] )
```

From the docs: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

### Edit

To elaborate, use Firebug or Developer Tools, something with a console, and type

`$('#timeline-content-slider').slider('value');`

to get the current value for the slider. You can then use

`$('#timeline-content-slider').slider('value','yourValueYouJustGotHere');`

to move the slider to that point.